# Проблема с запуском скрипта расположенного в папке

Tags: python, python-3.x

Собственно проблема на скриншоте. Не знаю, что добавить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А с чего вы решили, что ваш `Main.py` будет знать что-либо о модулях в родительской папке? Не проверять же ему всю ФС на предмет наличия их? Модули будут искаться в папках, указанных в `sys.path`, соответственно, надо туда добавить относительный или абсолютный путь папки, в которой лежат ваши модули, учитывая, что у вас это в родительской папке, то можно сделать так:

```
import sys
import os

# добавить относительный путь
sys.path.append('..')

# добавить абсолютный путь 
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), '..'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы упустили файл `__init__.py`, который должен содержаться в каждом пакете (папке), т.е. в у вас в папках: `libs/__init__.py`, `libs/lib1/__init__.py`, `libs/lib2/__init__.py` - он должен существовать.

Вот подробней: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

> The __init__.py files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case, __init__.py can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the **all** variable, described later.

Comment: Добавил. Ничего не изменилось: http://storage2.static.itmages.com/i/16/0315/h_1458083137_5409274_8e9c7d2f78.png

Comment: @SergeyPestov, вы определитесь какой `main` у вас реально **main** :) У вас по логике в корне проекта `main.py` файл, который как я понял и подразумевалось запускать, должен быть блок: `if __name__ == "main" ...` и последующая инициализация самого класса `Main` и передача управления методу `run`. А вот `proga1/Main.py` - почистите его, оставив только описание класса и запускайте корневой скрипт `main.py`.

Comment: Наверное вы правы.